# Open MVC view in a new window but pass a Model to the action instead of individual parameters

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I like to call an MVC action by passing parameters as a Model and I want to show the return view in a new Window.

I tried in two different ways as below from Javascript but it is not working:

**1.**

```
window.open(
    '@Url.Action("EIDLookUp", "LookUp")?details=' + JSON.stringify(labInputLDAPInput), 
    '',
    width=1024,    
    height=665,
    titlebar=1,
    toolbar=No,
    menubar=No,
    scrollbars=Yes,
    resizable=Yes,
    location=No,
    directories=No,
    status=Yes'
);
```

**2.**

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("EIDLookUp", "LookUp")',
    data: labInputLDAPInput,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (response) {
        var w = window.open();
        $(w.document.body).html(response.responseText);
    }
})
```

My Controller action looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EIDLookUp(LookUpDetails details) 
{

    GetDataFromLDAP empData = new GetDataFromLDAP();
    IEnumerable<SearchClientResult> employeeList = 
        empData.GetEIDLookUpData(details.eidLookUp, details.activeOnly);

    // Assign values to View Model
    //LookUpDetails details = new LookUpDetails();
    details.employeeList = employeeList;
    //details.found = found;
    //details.fieldID = fieldID;
    //details.multiple = multiple;
    //details.activeOnly = activeOnly;
    details.row = 1;

    return View("EIDLookUp", details);
}
```

Please let me know how to make this work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can send the data from the form back via the opt.2 you have used above so for the data parameter give it the serilised form instead of the var you have used.  data: $('<form selector>').serialize(), give it a try anyway

Answer (score 2):

Refer my comment, confirmed working, used the following as a test.
Haven't played with the html coming back but the viewModel in the controller will contain  all input values from the form.

ViewModel

```
public class LookUpDetails
{
    public int? FormId { get; set;  }
    public string UserValue { get; set; }
}
```

controller action

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EIDLookUp(TestModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "For Submitted with uservalue from form = " + viewModel.UserValue;
        }
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

cshtml

```
@model TestModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @name = "testForm" }))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FormId)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.UserValue)

    <input type="button" class="submit-dummy" value="Submit" />
}
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".submit-dummy").on("click", function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")',
                data: $("form[name=testForm]").serialize(),
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (response) {
                    var w = window.open();
                    $(w.document.body).html(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your example is one of the very rare examples of a view change. I adapted your example for use in a dropdownlistfor. all i had to do was change .on("click",   to .on("change". below i will post my change just as example.  Bedankt!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to send a model to an MVC action, but the model sent has to be in json format and it needs to have all it's properties name matching the entity.

For example I was suing knockout to do do that:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/yourcontroller/EIDLookUp",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: ko.toJSON(LookUpDetails),
    dataType: "json",
    error: function (resp) {
         alert("ERROR\n" + resp.responseText);
    },
    success: function (data) {
         $(".notification").show();
    }
});
LookUpDetails = {
  Name : ko.observable()
};
```

You can populate the `LookUpDetails` object in your view by mapping it with knockout data-bind. (http://knockoutjs.com/)

If you don't want to use knockout or any other library, I think you can still do it using:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/yourcontroller/EIDLookUp",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   data: JSON.stringify(LookUpDetails),
   dataType: "json",
   error: function (resp) {
         alert("ERROR\n" + resp.responseText);
   },
   success: function (data) {
         $(".notification").show();
   }
});
```

and manually map the `LookUpDetails` with form data by using jquery `.val()`  ex: `$('name').val()`

The key here is that the json object has to match with your entity.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by mvandersteen is exactly right. and a rare one. I use the code below when I change the selected value in a dropdownlistfor and do a httppost and give the model as a parameter.

```
@section Scripts
{
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")  // these scripts are not important for this example
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/SGLRegistration.js")

    <script type="text/javascript">  //here it gets interesting
        $(".jsddlCustomer").on("change", function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")',
                data: $("form[name=dataRegistrationForm]").serialize(),
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (response) {
                    var w = window.open();
                    $(w.document.body).html(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

My dropdownlist is declared in this way:

```
<div id="tempCustomerselect">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CustomerName)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PitchID, new SelectList((new SGLDataRegistration.Models.CustomerModel().GetRoles()).OrderBy(x => x.CustomerName), "PitchID", "CustomerName"), new {id = "ddlCustomer", @class="jsddlCustomer"})
</div>
```

Hope this is helpful for somebody, I have searched for many many hours for this.